# removing header and indexes when iterating the groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to remove header for each group while iterating.
I have requirement to group by few column and dataframe value for that group

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('D:\\Python-pandas-numpy-mat_learn\\panda-learn\\test.xlsx')
#column in dataframes are: ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
grp=df.groupby(by=['col1','col2'])
for each in grp.groups:
    print(df[(df['col1']==each[0]) & (df['col2']==each[1])])
#Output is: 
   col1  col2  col3   col4
9    32   321    12  5mlds
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   123    34    44  Row1
1   123    34    66  Row2
   col1  col2  col3 col4
6   214   321  3255  ere
#Want output like 
   col1  col2  col3   col4
    32   321    12  5mlds
   123    34    44  Row1
   123    34    66  Row2
   214   321  3255  ere
```

I don't want headers (['col1','col2','col3','col4']) and indexes for each group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you really need to use a loop, one option:

```
grp=df.groupby(by=['col1','col2'])

for i, (each, g) in enumerate( grp):
    print(g.to_string(index=False).split('\n', maxsplit=min(i,1))[-1])
```

Output:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
   32   321    12 5mlds
  123    34    44 Row1
  123    34    66 Row2
  214   321  3255  ere
```